# Gluing small parts with hairspray?

Tags: glue

Someone told me about a "myth" that you could glue LEGO pieces together with a solidifying hairspray like Tresemme stuff, or similar firm hairsprays (that ones that solidify your hair and dry out fast)

Id rather not test it on a random brick to know, but I have a few sets of rare limited edition model weapons (Like Actual Silver versions of LEGO Ninjago weapons and other such common rares, but I also have some extremely rare things like the gold-plated minifig katana)... And I keep losing the pieces to them (I usually find them but still!!) And Due that I'm only using them for collection (not play) I don;t need them to be seperable.

Keep in mind, I'm not really applying this question to my 1 piece rares or my metal minifigure items. I also have some old limited edition plastics that no longer "exist" and they tend to be weapons and pieces made from multiple small pieces.

Is something like hairspray a workable method (Ive heard its similar to those "bead glues" that you see on TV where you make plastic beads, and spray them with something and they stick together...

if this isn't a good method to go about with this, Perhaps a better method that's not expensive nor messy, but works well and looks good.

I plan on later getting an artist to line them up and put them in Epoxy resin, but for now I need a glue method (For bragging rights :3)

Comment: Hi Taylor! Could you please expand on your reluctance, why are you unwilling to try this method with two common, easily replaceable pieces?

Comment: @zovits I dont have common pieces. I only collect rares or exceptionally popular pieces (Red darth vader helm, purple ninja ghi, silver METAL weapons, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK those "bead glues" work on a completely different principle where the sheen on the individual beads is a water-activated glue and so the finished piece needs to be sprayed with just clean water to adhere the beads together.

There are a number of "weak glues" known which could be worth a try:

- thick sugar syrup (naturally water soluble, thus removable)
- a mixture of baking flour and water (similarly water soluble)
- from [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8106/3631) comes a recommendation for the "Spray and Play" glue, which can be found for sale online but whose website has since gone rogue. Probably due to the negative feedback received on Amazon.

Of course, for any of the above I'd recommend trying with a few pairs of expendable bricks, whose total cost might be lower than any one of your prized collectibles.

Another avenue would be to increase the clutch power to prevent the separation of the pieces. For example you could place thin pieces of paper, saran wrap or tinfoil between the LEGO pieces that need to be held together. The additional material will prevent the pieces from returning to their original shapes, this tension will make accidental separation harder. And if you get the size of the insert small enough and the placement precise enough, nothing will stick out from between the bricks and so the insert will not degrade the display value.